# Overuse of NSView -> Alternatives?

Tags: objective-c, macos, performance, cocoa, nsview

I having some Performance troubles with my app:

It takes more than 2 seconds to load -> So straight away I went to Apple documentation

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaPerformance/Articles/CustomViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001443-CJBJIFGC

In the section named "Avoid the Overuse of Views" at the bottom I got very confused:

I indeed adding a lot of `NSViews` (Guess I overusing them).

"
Instead, you should consider writing your own custom classes that can be managed by a higher-level `NSView` subclass. The drawing code of your `NSView` subclass can then be optimized to handle your custom objects.
"

My Question is:

How can I write my own custom classes that can be managed by a higher -level `NSView` subclass -> any example ?

Only thing I thought was a `CALayer`.

Is adding `CALayer` subclasses are better than adding `NSView` ?
Would it increase my poor performance a bit ?

Or there is something new to learn ?

EDIT:

Currently I have `NSView`s where I adding 15 `NSView` as a subview to them and I can add 15`CALayer`s instead :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you profiled your App? Before ripping your view hierarchy apart, use instruments with the time profiler to find out where the time is actually being spent.

CALayers are more efficient than UIViews, and it is recommended to avoid using drawRect if you don't need to, but before resorting to a rewrite, you need to know where your App is actually spending its time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you please provide more clarity on the part "avoid using drawRect", if all I need is a solid `fillRect` should I avoid the `drawRect` and make the `NSView.layer.setBackgroundColor` instead?

Comment: If all I needed was a solid filled rect, I would use a CALayer with backGroundColor rather than a UIView. I would use UIView's if I needed gestureRecognizers or other view-dependent things. Your suggestion is probably good too. However, as I said in the answer: start with instruments and see where the time is actually going.